# Changing WebSphere's JVM to x64

Tags: 64-bit, websphere, java

Recently i had installed WebSphere Portal 6.1 on my computer with Windows7 x64.
But i had discovered that it runs on 32 version of JVM.

How can i make it run on x64 ?
Should i reinstall webSphere or its just enough to swap java folder ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM's products (WebSphere Application Server, WebSphere Portal Server and others) are only supported (and in fact, can only work) when running with an IBM-provided JDK. The way IBM handles x64 products is *not* by having you just "switch Java folders"; you actually have to download the x64 edition of the product in question.

According to this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27019366, WebSphere Portal 6.1 is *not* supported for production purposes on Windows 7 x64; there are instructions there as to what to do in order to get it working (you need to get a fresh 6.1.5.2 installation from IBM), but you should find out with IBM whether you can run it in a production environment "at your own risk" or is it violating any license.

According to the same link, WPS 6.1 is supported in x64 mode under other Microsoft x64 OS's (such as Windows Server 2008).

Isaac

Comment: Im currently using it for development purposes and need to maximize it's speed.
Thanks for answer!